# Array in php with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have code like this:

```
$data = array();
for(int $i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++)
   $data[$i][] = 5;
```

I don't know what's name of `$data[$i][] = 5;` in php and how to write this code in javascript?

or other hands, how can I write code above in javascript?

Thanks

P/s:
 I want to write that code on nodeJs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `Array#push` to add a element for array

```
var data = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
   if(!data[i]) data[i] = [];
   data[i].push(5);
```

Comment: This seems error: 
data[i][].push(5);
           ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]

Comment: seems, working, Thanks but what's name of this code `$data[$i][] = 5` in php? or how is working with that code?

Comment: `$data[$i][] = 5`  equivalent `$data[$i][count($data[$i])] = 5` to add a new element to array

Comment: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined. seem not working...

I'm coding in node js

Comment: as i comment, you need set `data[i] = []`


`var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
  data[i] = [];
  data[i].push(5);
}`

Comment: @haidn: you need check `data[i]` ,if undefined, you must init an array for `data[i]`, same as my code above, i had updated

Answer (score 1):

[Array.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is a function used to insert a value into an array. But you can also use the C like way `data[i] = 'value'`.

```js
data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  data.push([5]);

document.write(JSON.stringify(data))
```

As an alternative use

```js
data = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
   data[i] = [5];

document.write(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

in this case, can understand `$data[$i][] = 5;` as below

```js
$data[$i] = array();
array_push($data[$i],5);
// ex: [ 0 => [0 => 5]]
```

in Javascipt:

```js
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
  data[i] = [];
  data[i].push(5);
}
```

Comment: awesome!!. What I need. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `array.push()` to add an item to the end of the array.

```
var sample = new Array();
sample.push(new Object());
```

To do this n times use a for loop.

```
var n = 100;
var sample = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    sample.push(new Object());
```

Note that you can also substitute new `Array()` with [] and new `Object()` with {} so it becomes:

```
var n = 100;
var sample = [];
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    sample.push({});
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript code:

```
var data = [];
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    data[i] = [];
    data[i][data[i].length] = 5;
}
```